# How Can Make Multi Counter Application with Vanilla JS and Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

Here is my code. I want to make multiple counter application with vanilla js and redux. But when I click on the "Add" fields, it just changes my primary counter value—not creating a new counter itself. But I want it to make another counter while clicking on the "Add" Button. Check the link, for example.

[Wanna make the actual same](https://redux-multi-counter-app.netlify.app)

What has to change in my code?

```js
//select dom element
let counterCountainer = document.getElementById("counter-container");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");

// create initial state
let initialState = [
    {
        id: 1,
        value: 0,
    },
];

// create variable fro unique id
let id = 1;

// action identifiers
const INCREMENT = "increment";
const DECREMENT = "decrement";
const ADD = "add";

// create reducer function
function counterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === ADD) {
        const copyState = [...state];
        copyState.push({
            id: ++id,
            value: id - 1,
        });
        return copyState;
    } else if (action.type === INCREMENT) {
        const copyState = [...state];
        console.log(copyState);
        console.log(action);
        const index = copyState.findIndex(
            (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
        );

        copyState[index].value += action.payload.value;
        console.log(copyState);
        return copyState;
    } else if (action.type === DECREMENT) {
        const copyState = [...state];
        const index = copyState.findIndex(
            (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
        );
        copyState[index].value -= action.payload.value;
        return copyState;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

// create store
const store = Redux.createStore(counterReducer, initialState);

// action creators
const increment = (id, value) => {
    return {
        type: INCREMENT,
        payload: {
            value: value,
            id: id,
        },
    };
};

const decrement = (id, value) => {
    return {
        type: DECREMENT,
        payload: {
            value: value,
            id: id,
        },
    };
};

// create new counter div when click add counter button
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    store.dispatch({
        type: "add",
    });
});

// create render function for show updated state in ui
function render() {
    const state = store.getState();
    state.forEach((item) => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList =
            "p-4 h-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-5 bg-white rounded shadow counter";
        const counter = document.createElement("div");
        counter.classList = "text-2xl font-semibold";
        div.appendChild(counter);
        counter.innerText = item.value;
        const btnContainer = document.createElement("div");
        btnContainer.classList = "flex space-x-3";
        const incrementBtn = document.createElement("button");
        incrementBtn.classList =
            "bg-indigo-400 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded shadow";
        incrementBtn.innerText = "Increment";
        incrementBtn.onclick = function () {
            store.dispatch(increment(item.id, item.id));
        };
        const decrementBtn = document.createElement("button");
        decrementBtn.classList =
            "bg-red-400 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded shadow";
        decrementBtn.innerText = "Decrement";
        decrementBtn.onclick = function () {
            store.dispatch(decrement(item.id, item.id));
        };
        btnContainer.appendChild(incrementBtn);
        btnContainer.appendChild(decrementBtn);
        div.appendChild(btnContainer);
        counterCountainer.innerHTML = "";
        counterCountainer.append(div);
    });
}

// update ui initially
render();

// subscribe store
store.subscribe(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Simple Counter Application</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <!-- import redux from cdn -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@latest/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="w-screen min-h-screen p-10 bg-gray-100 text-slate-700">
        <!-- header -->
        <h1 class="max-w-md mx-auto text-center text-2xl font-bold">
            Simple Multi Counter Application
        </h1>

        <!-- counters -->
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-md mt-10 space-y-5" id="counter-container"></div>
        <div class="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-md text-center">
            <button id="add" class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded shadow">
                    Add Counter
                </button>
            <button id="reset" class="bg-red-400 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded shadow">
                    Reset
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The website you linked has unobfuscated code: https://redux-multi-counter-app.netlify.app/script.js Just have a look at it?

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage entities with RTK, it's to use [`createEntityAdapter`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createentityadapter) utils

```js
interface Counter {
  id: string
  value: number
}

const counterAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Counter>({
  selectId: (counter) => counter.id,
  sortComparer: (a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value),
})

export const {
  selectById: selectCounterById,
} = usersAdapter.getSelectors()

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: counterAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    increment(state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: string }>) {
      const counter = selectCounterById(state, action.payload.id);
      counter.value = counter.value + 1;
      counterAdapter.upsertOne(state, counter);
    },
  },
})
```